# How to find the function calling error in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I meet a function calling error in Dymola, so I try to find the reason and where I call the function in the model. Here is the error information:
[image]

[image]

The reason is that the enthalpy is negative.

Based on the error information, I could find the definition of the parameter, but I can't find the place where the model calls the function.

So if I wanna debug this error, how could I continue?

[image]

Comment: Not a full solution, but one possible first step would be to `Generate a listing of translated Modelica code in dsmodel.mof` or at least `flat Modelica` and search in there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am using a commercial library, I can't generate the .mof file or flat Modelica. A disaster for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mew package in the Package Browser.
Duplicate the function, and place into the newly
created package.
Create a new Record in this package,with another name.
Cut and paste all the lines start with "input".

Because the code is no longer in a funtion, we should declare each of the "input"
in the copied code as "parameter".

Then, edit the duplicated function by adding a line which starts with an ‘input’
 command, and followed by drag and drops the function from the package browser 
into this line. Please note that do not forget to terminate the line by inserting a 
semi-column ';' at the end of this line.

Rename the duplicated/modified function like the second one created
in the package you created at the beginning.

I recommend you save the package location.

Verify that you have it correct and you would not have errors in the calls.